# In what form to use verb after "i have never"

Tags: grammar, verbs

If i want to say that `i have never (got,get,gotten) a tattoo` which verb should i use?

Comment: Technically, it's preset perfect, so it be should got/gotten. You may want to read more on got vs gotten and have got vs have. Also such questions suit English Language Learners Stackexchange more as this site is focused on more difficult issues and subtle nuances of the language usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "got and gotten " are correct, just US, UK fact.